# detecting a change in list and updating it to sql

Tags: c#, web-services, list

I have a function that caches the results from the SQL table.

```
private List<RMSResponse> FetchData()
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from RMSResponse", conn))
    {
            selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader rdr = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                GlobalData.Add(new RMSResponse { RecruitID = Int32.Parse(rdr["CandidateID"].ToString()), TimeStamp = rdr.GetDateTime(4), Type = ConvertBool(rdr.GetBoolean(2)) });
            }
            rdr.Close();
            return GlobalData;
    }
}
```

I have another list that I get from a web service. It only contains `RecruitID` and `Timestamp`.

```
NegativeResponseList = rms.NegativeResponse.Where(d => d.RLMSTimeStamp != null && d.RLMSTimeStamp > new DateTime(2012, 02, 22)).ToList();
```

A RecruitID could be removed from the     `NegativeResponseList` and put into the     `PositiveNegativeResponseList`. Ofcourse, I wouldnt know this, I am getting the data from a webservice.

Since the globaldata contains the type (could be negative or positive). How can I update the table in SQL?

I am doing it like this, but its not working out and is very inefficient.

```
        foreach (var Response in GlobalData)
        {
            foreach (var NegativeResponse in NegativeResponseList)
            {
                if (Response.RecruitID == NegativeResponse.RLMSRecruitId)
                {
```